# Selectively use marshal_with on GET response in Flask-RESTful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm working on an API using Flask-RESTful. Using this API I want to be able to select if a GET enpoint has to return JSON or HTML.

When I call `/shipments/ready` without any extra variables, I want to return a JSON object with all shipments that have their status set to 'ready'. This doesn't give any problems.
But I also want to be able to call this same endpoint from within Javascript and give it a `format=html` flag, in which case the endpoint has to return the same data but as an HTML string (using a Jinja2 template).

I got this to work by looking at `request.args` and see if the `format` flag was set (see below code). But I also want to use `@marshal_with` to format the JSON response. When I use this modifier, the HTML response doesn't work anymore (a JSON object with the fields like specified in `shipments_fields`, but all set to `null` is returned instead).
I was able to create a workaround by moving the `@marshal_with` to a separate function, but I can't imagine this is the best approach.

Does anyone know how this is supposed to be done?

```python
shipments_fields = {
    'id':                   fields.Integer,
    # etc...
}

@marshal_with(shipments_fields)
def marshal_shipments(result):
    return result

class Shipments_by_status(Resource):
    def get(self, status):
        shipments = models.Shipment.query.filter_by(status=status).all()

        # If asking for HTML
        try: # Try, to prevent errors when 'format' is not existing
            if request.args['format'] == 'html':
                return render_template("page_snippets/shipment.html",\
                shipments=shipments), 200
        except:
            pass

        shipments = marshal_shipments(shipments)
        return shipments

api.add_resource(Shipments_by_status,   '/shipments/<string:status>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a separate function to marshal data is a good idea. But by default the response `Contenty-Type` is `application/json`. To make a html response, you have to make a response object by calling `make_resonse` fuction if `Accept` header has `text/html` in the request.

And you don't have to pass query string to request a html output, but your request `Accept` header should include `text/html`, that's default with the browsers.

```
def get(self, status):
    shipments = models.Shipment.query.filter_by(status=status).all()

    accept = request.headers.get('Accept')
    if accept and 'text/html' in accept:
            return make_reponse(render_template("page_snippets/shipment.html", shipments=shipments), 200)
    return marshal_shipments(shipments)
```

If you don't want to check request `Accept` header to render the right output for different media types, you have to define separate functions for each media types and register them with `api.representation` decorator.

```
@api.representation('text/html')
def output_html(data, code, headers=None):
    resp = make_reponse(render_template("page_snippets/shipment.html", shipments=data), 200)
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
    return resp

@api.representation('application/json')
def output_json(data, code, headers=None):
    resp = make_response(json.dumps(data), code)
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
    return resp

class Shipments_by_status(Resource):
    @marshal_with(shipments_fields)
    def get(self, status):
        return models.Shipment.query.filter_by(status=status).all()
```